# Python: replacing xml elements with multiprocessing

Tags: python, xml, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing, xml.etree

I have two different .xml Files and i want to create a program that replaces a child from 1.xml with the child from 2.xml
1.xml looks like this :

```
<CATALOG>
   <ITEM>
      <COLOR>11</COLOR>
      <COLORNAME>Black</COLORNAME>
   </ITEM>
   <ITEM>
      <COLOR>41</COLOR>
      <COLORNAME>Aqua</COLORNAME>
   </ITEM>
   <ITEM>
      ...
   </ITEM>
</CATALOG>
```

and 2.xml looks like this:

```
<CODES>
   <ITEM>
      <ITEMTYPE>P</ITEMTYPE>
      <ITEMID>44</ITEMID>
      <COLOR>Black</COLOR>
   </ITEM>
   <ITEM>
      <ITEMTYPE>P</ITEMTYPE>
      <ITEMID>44</ITEMID>
      <COLOR>Blue</COLOR>
   </ITEM>
   <ITEM>
      ...
   </ITEM>
</CODES>
```

my goal is to get a 3.xml file which should look like this:

```
<CODES>
   <ITEM>
      <ITEMTYPE>P</ITEMTYPE>
      <ITEMID>44</ITEMID>
      <COLOR>11</COLOR>
   </ITEM>
   <ITEM>
      <ITEMTYPE>P</ITEMTYPE>
      <ITEMID>44</ITEMID>
      <COLOR>7</COLOR>
   </ITEM>
   <ITEM>
      ...
   </ITEM>
</CODES>
```

i now wrote a script that changed the `<COLOR>` of 1.xml to the `<COLOR>` of 2.xml with comparing the `<COLORNAME>` from 2.xml with `<COLOR>` from 1.xml

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

codes = ET.parse('./datasets/1.xml')
root_codes = codes.getroot()

colors = ET.parse('./datasets/2.xml')
root_colors = colors.getroot()
done=0

for colorname in root_codes.findall('ITEM'):
    codes_color_name = colorname.find('COLOR').text
    for color in root_colors.iter('ITEM'):
        color_name = color.find('COLORNAME').text
        if codes_color_name == color_name:
            color_id = color.find('COLOR').text
            colorname.find('COLOR').text = str(color_id)
            codes.write('3.xml')
            done=done+1
    print(done)
```

I tried this with a cut-down version of 1.xml and it seems to work. As this is really slow (1.xml ~300k lines & 2.xml ~3k Lines) i tried to use multiprocessing and this is what i came up with:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
from multiprocessing import Pool
import multiprocessing
import os

codes = ET.parse('./datasets/1.xml')
root_codes = codes.getroot()

colors = ET.parse('./datasets/2.xml')
root_colors = colors.getroot()

def process_item(colorname):
    codes_color_name = colorname.find('COLOR').text
    for color in root_colors.iter('ITEM'):
        color_name = color.find('COLORNAME').text
        if codes_color_name == color_name:
            color_id = color.find('COLOR').text
            colorname.find('COLOR').text = str(color_id)
            codes.write('3.xml')
            break
if __name__ == '__main__':
    pool = Pool(os.cpu_count())
    pool.map(process_item, root_codes.findall('ITEM'))
```

I tried this with the cut-down version of 1.xml and it basically spits out the same file, with nothing changed. Is there a more efficient way to do this or what is wrong with my way of using multiprocessing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using multiprocessing is a different thing. Let's focus on optimizing it in first place.

The way code is working here is actually doing lot of unnecessary processing like finding the value of color each time from 1.xml while it can be pre-stored and used. Also while updating it is finding the color each time to update in 2.xml, both of these searching can be avoided here and just a simple traversal can solve the problem.

So what can be done to achieve that is maintaining a dict of pair (color_name, color_code). this dict can be fulfilled by traversing the 1.xml completely only once, then after preparation of this dict elements of 2.xml can be traversed and for each element color code value can be fetched from the dict and after updating color code of all the elements of 2.xml can be stored in 3.xml

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

codes = ET.parse('./datasets/1.xml')
root_codes = codes.getroot()

colors = ET.parse('./datasets/2.xml')
root_colors = colors.getroot()
done=0

color_code_dict = {}
for color_item in root_colors.iter('ITEM'):
    color_code = color_item.find('COLOR').text
    color_name = color_item.find('COLORNAME').text
    color_code_dict[color_name] = color_code


for code_item in root_codes.iter('ITEM'):
    code_color = code_item.find('COLOR').text
    code_item.find('COLOR').text = color_code_dict.get(code_color)

codes.write('3.xml')
print("Done")
```

P.S.: Make sure that colors and codes are being fetched from write files.